# Need help :Drive missing (E: & F:) after the reboot on windows7

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, symantec

i am getting similar issue described in below link:

http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/drive-missing-d-f-g-after-reboot-windows-7-pgp

I did a shrink on the C: drive, and created new volumes (E, F).

After some automatic windows updates I was asked to restart my laptop

Now all the hard disk drives except C: is missing. (ie, E, F).

When I go to disk management it shows only one volume C:

C: Simple Basic NTFS Healthy (System, Boot, Page File, Active Crash Dump, Primary Parition) 465.75 (Capacity) 465.75 (Free Space) 100% (% Free) No (Fault Tolerance) 0% (OverHead)

PGP Desktop also shows only C: as only parition available. Remaining paritions available earlier are gone now.

Not sure how to solve out,seems my all data in drive E and F: got lost....how to recover and make drive visible?

Same issue is reported via above given link.

Comment: check in cmd,type DISKPART opening new window after type list volume.it will showing all volumes.in ltr(2 field) field letter D and G doesn't show type assign volume d and also assign volume g.it will show hidden volumes..

Comment: DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info

  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     D                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
 
 Volume 1     C   SYSTEM       NTFS   Partition    465 GB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2     G                       Removable       0 B  No Media
here missing drives E & F is not showing

Comment: my missing drives are E and F,sorry for the typo @newguy

Comment: what is C: drive memory size before shrink?

Comment: 465GB before shrink,current size is 121gb in which 71gb is free

Comment: from your list volume result C volume size is mentioned 465GB?

Comment: yes,but i had already did partitioning,dun know how come those drive disappeared with datas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19684/discussion-between-new-guy-and-akshay).

Comment: sfc /scannow is not showing error,still not able to sort out this issue :(

Comment: Did you try a checkdisk on C?

Comment: checkdisk is even not helpful,its showing me 121gb data...and checkdisk on e: & F : is giving error.
 C:\windows\system32>chkdsk E:
Cannot open volume for direct access.

Comment: how to recover data,any recommended tool for this situation?

Comment: used testdisk to restore data & it worked like a charm...will see wat to do next to make drive visible